# Google sheets: how to get the last value in the column that has the same value in the previous column?

Tags: google-sheets, formula, spreadsheet, worksheet-function, formulas

```
Name    Number
Alpha   5
Echo    2
Charlie 6
Alpha   1
Delta   5
Bravo   7
Alpha   3
Echo    2
Charlie 5
Bravo   2
```

For example from above, I have names in column A and numbers in column B.

I need a formula to get all the last value of a specific name, for example:
Alpha should return 3,
Bravo should return 2,
Charlie should return 5 etc.

I currently only know how to return the last value in the entire column with:

```
=INDEX(FILTER(I:I,NOT(ISBLANK(I:I))),ROWS(FILTER(I:I,NOT(ISBLANK(I:I)))))
```

But it cannot return the last value of a specific value from another column.

Please help, thank you in advance.

Comment: Do you need this formula to run for one "Name" at a time? I.e. just for "Alpha"? Or does it need to calculate it the "Number" for all values in the Name column?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that

1. The first row is a header row
2. Name column is A
3. Number column is B
4. The specific name whose last number value you want is listed in cell `C2`

Your formula (in column `D2`) should be

```
=INDEX(FILTER(B2:B, A2:A=C2), COUNTA(FILTER(B2:B, A2:A=C2)), 1)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
=SORTN(SORT(A1:B10,ROW(A1:A10),0),2^9,2,1,1)
```

- SORT the array in reverse with ROW numbers
- SORTN to remove duplicates

Answer (score 0):

Try,

```
=index(I:I, max(filter(row(I:I), H:H=K2)))
```

[image]